# Adding new data to a state in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I working on a project where I am using react.js with laravel where I am using react for adding new comment in a post for that I am trying to to react's state but I want to add new data retrieved from server in my state without deleting or erasing old data present from that state. How can I achieve that method, is there any dependency for that, or any example or tutorial for that? Even If I am going with wrong approach then also please tell me what approach will be perfect.

The sample code for my problem - 
I've an ajax function to get data initially.

```
getData: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:        '/get-data',
        dataType:   'json',
        cache:      false,
        success:    function(data) {
            this.setState({
                data: data 
            });
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

and now after triggering new event I want to update my state without loosing my old data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [react immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

This allows you to update nested parts of the state without having to reset the whole thing. If you are just manipulating the root level properties of the state (e.g. `this.state.blah` or `this.state.foo`) then `this.setState({ foo: 'a value'});` will leave the other root elements as they were.

If you do then want to completely reset the state you can use `replaceState({});`

[setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

[replaceState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate)

Comment: Thanks. But I am retrieving a JSON data from server. Even in my state, I've stored JSON data having more than 15 attributes. I'll try your method with my case. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Can you update your question with some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` in your code is a valid `JSON` object, you can use something like:

- [`object-assign`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign)
- [`lodash.merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge)

to merge your data before setting it to `state.data`. An example using `lodash.merge`:

```
import merge from 'lodash.merge'

// some of your code

// inside your getData function in your components
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
        this.setState({
            data: merge({}, this.state.data, data)
        });
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Whilst it may be not a good practice to be doing this sort of wholesome replacement, it should address your issue. What might be a better approach is not really a scope of this answer :D